# Show dijit/Menu programmatically

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

I am working on a context menu in dijit. The code is almost done and the menu pops up as I right click the attached dom node. **The problem is that I need to be able to show/hide the menu programmatically.** It appears that there is no method like .show() or .hide()

here is the code:

```
var top_settings_menu;

require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/Menu"], function(ready, Menu) {
    ready(function() {
        top_settings_menu = new Menu();
        top_settings_menu.bindDomNode("settings");

        ...menu items
        ........

       top_settings_menu.startup();

    });
});
```

Here is what I need:
Method to show hide the menu programmatically like:
    top_settings_menu.show();
    top_settings_menu.hide();

Answer (score 1):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/nVqmh/4/) demonstrates two approaches, but I don't know if there's an official way to do this.

Setup the menu:

```
var pMenu;

require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/Menu", "dijit/MenuItem", "dijit/PopupMenuItem"], function (ready, Menu, MenuItem) {
    ready(function () {
        pMenu = new Menu({
            targetNodeIds: ["progmenu"]
        });
        pMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
            label: "Simple menu item"
        }));
        pMenu.startup();
    });
});

function runAfterDelay(fn, ms) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Timeout " + new Date());
        fn();
    }, ms);
}
```

Add the event handling.

- Approach #1 is to call `dijit/popup.close()`, passing the menu as the single parameter.
- Approach #2 synthesises a `blur` event to 'trick' the menu into closing.

...

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dijit/popup"], function (dom, on, popup) {
    var timeout = 3000;
    on(dom.byId("btnPopupClose"), "click", function () {
        runAfterDelay(function () {
            if (pMenu) {
                console.log("Calling .close()");
                popup.close(pMenu);
            }
        }, timeout);
    });
    on(dom.byId("btnTriggerBlur"), "click", function () {
        runAfterDelay(function () {
            var opts = {
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true
            };
            console.log("emitting blur event");
            on.emit(pMenu.domNode, "blur", opts);
        }, timeout);
    });
});
```